# New question lists have too much space between tags and user name when tags occupy two rows

Tags: bug, design

The new question list does a pretty good job of keeping the user name and time of the last modification on the same line as the tags if it all fits in the window width, and drop down the name if it doesn't. But if the tags list is broken across two rows, then the name and time are put on their own line, even if they would fit on the same line as the second row of tags. See screen shot below.

Obviously the right placement for the name + time information is on the same row as the last tag, if it fits there.

This happens on very small screens, and I can make it happen on my desktop too if I make the window narrow enough.

[image: too much space]

---

**NOTE** that this is not addressed in answers to [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el) —- sure, I could post a bug report as an answer there, but it will likely get overlooked among 4 pages of angry, highly critical answers that the devs don’t want to look at. Let’s move on from that post, shall we?

Comment: On PC it's not any better, there's too much space to the left of the score panel too. I guess "responsive view" kicked up a few issues from the compromises that had to be made.

Comment: Related, identical on a wider screen: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376117/282094 - but as it says there, how else should it be presented.

Comment: @Rob That is not the issue I’m pointing out (and is not an actual issue, it’s a nit-pick without solution). This one happens when tags occupy two rows.

Comment: @Rob: I think the solution for the issue I'm printing out here is obvious: the name + time can move up to be on the same row as the last tag (but I'll edit that in if you like). In the answer you linked, the name + time information doesn't fit with the tags, it needs to go to a new row. The poster didn't like that, but offered no alternative.

Comment: Search for something else that helps you more: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372401/282094    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314089/282094 - there's no reason for the above to jump the line in front of everyone else. --- Staff does read each one, as evidenced by other recent announcements.

Comment: *sure, I could post a bug report as an answer there, but it will likely get overlooked among 4 pages of angry, highly critical answers that the devs don’t want to look at. Let’s move on from that post, shall we?* - No, let's keep the bug reports there please. And essentially this is covered in the various "too much whitespace" answers.

Comment: @Tim -- it's not. This is an actual bug in the logic, not a "I prefer less whitespace" thing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo you can argue bug or intentional feature, but the outcome is you’re saying there’s too much whitespace.